# Update sql data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, sql, angularjs

I need to update data using angular
I have SQL table(task list) with columns: id, taskname, date, prior
I need to have possibility to update only current field, using keypress
Field need to be updated according to its id.

HTML

```
    <div class="task-list" ng-repeat="x in names">
           <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" value="{{x.prior}}" ng-keypress="UpdateInfo()"/>
           </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" value="{{x.taskname}}" ng-keypress="UpdateInfo()"/> <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="DeleteInfo()" value="Delete"/> 
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-5">
               <input type="date" value="{{x.startdate}}" ng-keypress="UpdateInfo()"/>
           </div>


  </div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.UpdateInfo = function(){  
           $http.post(  
                "update.php",  
                {'taskname':$scope.taskname, 'comments':$scope.comments, 'prior':$scope.prior, 'startdate':$scope.startdate }  
           ).success(function(data){  
                alert(data);  
               if (data == true) {
getInfo();
}

           });  
      }
```

PHP
 There I tried to update only taskname

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  
 if(count($data) > 0)  
 {  
     $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->id);
      $taskname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->taskname);       
      $comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->comments);  
     $startdate= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->startdate);  
     $prior= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->prior);
     $query = "UPDATE tbl_user SET taskname='$taskname' WHERE id='$id'";
      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
      {  
           echo "Data Update...";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'Error';  
      }  
 }
```

After keypress I see only "Data Update...".But taskname isn't updated.

Comment: You don't send `id` in your JSON object.

Comment: This is definitely the issue!

Comment: @Chris can you explain more detail what I need to change to solve the problem? I already  has id in my SQL table and it's workin' ok, when I add new task

Comment: You're trying to do an UPDATE but your PHP code doesn't know the ID you are trying to update. This needs to be included in the list of fields you are sending in your POST request

Comment: @Chris ID  AUTO_INCREMENT I don't define value for this field

Comment: That's OK for when you're INSERTing a new record but if you want to update a specific record using UPDATE then you need to specify which ID you want to update.

Comment: @Chris Ok.Now I understood what you mean. How can I specify ID. Am I need to use something like $http.post("update.php?action=update_entry",$scope.id)  or define Id in another place?

Comment: Just add it after 'startdate':$scope.startdate in your controller. e.g. 'id':$scope.id

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a POST request so I don't think you need:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Instead refer to the variables as `$_POST['taskname']` and so on ..

Comment: Nope, they do because the request isn't form encoded. Unless Angular does that by default?

Comment: Yes, let's see. In my angular apps I use http.post and don't set any form encoding. In my backend API I access the variables via $_POST and not php://input

Comment: Anyway, whatever angular does, this isn't the issue :P